# How to print only cell output in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I make my excercises in Notebook. 10s in a row. I do the calculations in cells and I only want to print the output (pdf). But how could I do that?

I have this cell:

[image]

And I just want the output to be printed. Did I overlook that option (searched Stackoverflow for it)? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _print the output (pdf)_ ?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://myst-nb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/hiding.html)?

Comment: Exactly! So I now understand cells can have tags. `hide-input` would be my solution. Is it possible to tag the whole notebook?